# DimPlot of unused argument umap

Tags: r

I followed the: https://github.com/jumphone/BEER

Thanks in advance for any great help!

Best,

Yue

```
> DimPlot(pbmc_batch, reduction.use='umap', group.by='batch', pt.size=0.1) 
Error in DimPlot(pbmc_batch, reduction.use = "umap", group.by = "batch",  : 
  unused argument (reduction.use = "umap")
```

Comment: Is there any question you wanted to ask?

Comment: Hello jay.sf, Thank you so much! It should: reduction="umap".